Spring IntegrationTests: Execute init.sql just one before all tests and application startup
as from the title I'd like to pre-populate the DB used for integration tests before all the tests and the application starts. I tried with @Sql but it doesn't solve either of the requirements.
N.B. If you have an answer please, explain how things work and/or point to your source. Thanks.
